# C# setting a range of numbers within a class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

so i need to create a class with the following information, i have created or at least made one with the most the information below, how ever i'm having trouble setting the range of numbers for Matriculation number and for year mark and was wondering if anybody could help me out

Implement a class of type Student in C#, the class should be contained within a file
Student.cs. The class should conform the following specification:

Property                          Example               Data Validation

FirstName                         “Basil”               Not blank

SecondName                        “Fawlty”              Not blank

Date Of Birth                     23/08/1946            Not blank

Course                            “MA Hotel Management” Not blank

Matriculation Number              12345                 In the range 10000 to 99999

Year Mark                         55                    In range 0 -100

heres what i have so far for my class, hopefully its correct so far

```
namespace Student
{
    public class Student
    {
        private string firstname;
        private string secondname;
        private double dateofbirth;
        private string course;
        private int    matricnumber;
        private int    yearmark;

        public Student() 
        {
            firstname = "Basil";
            secondname = "Fawlty";
            dateofbirth = 23/08/1946;
            course = "MA Hotel Management";
            matricnumber = 12345;
            yearmark = 55;
        }
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return firstname; }
            set { firstname = value; }
        }

        public string SecondName
        {
            get { return secondname; }
            set { secondname = value; }
        }
        public double DateOfBirth 
        {
            get { return dateofbirth; }
            set { dateofbirth = value; }
        }

        public string Course
        {
            get { return course; }
            set { course = value; }
        }
        public int Matricnumber
        {
            get { return matricnumber; }
            set { matricnumber = value; }
        }
        public int YearMark
        {
            get { return yearmark; }
            set {yearmark = value; }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Help you out with what exactly? You forgot to mention your problem.

Comment: Do you intend to validate the number on input? Just do a check in the `Matricnumber` setter. If it's outside the range, throw an exception or clamp it to a valid value within the range.

Comment: It's too bad the [tag:Homework] tag is obsolete... This one is ripe for it.

Comment: I wish there was a "like" button for comments @smdrager :-)

Comment: Note that your date of birth is 0 (you are using division).  Checkout the DateTime (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) struct.

Comment: user1760510 - note that you can still edit the question. Clarify it enough and it might be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement some logic in your setter to check to see if the value is valid.  So pretend I needed a property called `LastName` on some class that could only be "Johnson", "Smith" or "Roberts".  I could do something like this:

```
private string _lastName;
public string LastName
{
    get { return _lastName; }
    set
    {
        if (value == "Johnson" || value == "Smith" || value == "Roberts")
        {
            _lastName = value;
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something here. Maybe set a default.  Maybe throw an exception. Whatever.
        }
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I didn't write an *exact* solution, since it really sounds like this is homework.

Comment: yeh i thought i would be something like that but would that mean im going to have to type every number manualy from 0 - 100 or 10000 - 99999,
iis there not a away so that dont have to that,

Comment: @Gromer Even if it is homework, you could answer for the matricnumber and he/she will be able to figure out how to solve yearmark.

Comment: Since you're talking about numbers, you can use `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=`.  No need to do a long if like `if (value == 1 || value ==2 ... || value == 9999)`.

Comment: @Nick, honestly wasn't sure what the SO opinion on an answer to a HW question was, that's why I changed it a bit.

Comment: @Gromer **CHALLENGE ACCEPTED**

Comment: @Gromer LOL I wrote a LINQPad script to output the full `if (value == 1 || value == 2 .. || value == 9999)` text. Copy/pasted into VS2010 -- hard crash to desktop. _challenge failed_ :(

Comment: Legit attitude, @user1760510!

Comment: id rather you didnt give me the proper answer away as i wont learn as much that way
thanks for the help

Comment: @Gromer Got VS2010 to take it. But then the compiler throws an error (one I have never seen before): `An expression is too long or complex to compile` Looks like I'll have to settle for `>` and `<`.

Comment: @user1760510 In this case, the proper answer is a fairly fundamental aspect of C#; it'd be difficult to describe it otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the data validation in the "set" method.  Throw an exception if the user inputs an invalid value.

```
    public int Matricnumber
    {
        get { return matricnumber; }
        set { 
               if (value > 99999 | value < 10000)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid value - MaticNumber must be in the range 10000-99999");
               matricnumber = value;
            }
    }
```

On the values that cannot be empty, you will presumably need to supply some type of Validate() method to verify this using String.IsNullOrEmpty after the fact, because there is no sense in initializing the class with default values.

Does this make sense?

Comment: You should be throwing an ArgumentOutOfRangeException to be clearer as to the error that's occuring

Comment: after the if part could i not put else then have a error message display in a messgae box or something?

Comment: @user1760510 @rmayer06: The `if` condition is incorrectly using only 1 pipe. It _should_ be: `if (value > 99999 || value < 10000)` with two pipes.

Comment: @user1760510 - No, definitely not. Do not implement side-effects and/or GUI in a property. MessageBox is out.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair `|` or `||` does not matter at all here.

Comment: @user1760510 you could present the `MessageBox` to the user within the setter, however, that would result in mixing your presentation layer with the rest of the code.  It'd be better to give the exception being thrown a proper message and then catch the exception by the UI layer and display the exception message there

Comment: @HenkHolterman Oh yeah, guess so since they're both boolean results. But if the value was greater than `99999` then it would continue to check (and get `value` again) the second condition. With `||` it will stop checking once one condition evaluates as true. So yeah, compiles and runs, that's my mistake.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, but it doesn't matter since this is an entirely academic thing.

Comment: yeh just look at the next part of it and i need to write a method in the class  so that if you get a mark below x then you fail, or higher than x you pass which is straight enough to do, suppose no harm in wirting a meathod or for the if statement to call the meathods to give the correct messgae if the values arent withing the range

thanks all for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you want validation on/by the class, you can do something like:

```
    public int Matricnumber
    {
        get { return matricnumber; }
        set 
        {
           if (value < MinMatric || value > MaxMatric)
             throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Matricnumber"); 
           matricnumber = value; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` seems more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not specify the behavior you want to prevent a bad value to be set.

In general, I would be a fan of [code contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287492.aspx) for the restriction requirements you specify.  Here is one way to use Contracts to solve the problem.

```
[ContractInvariantMethod]
private void ObjectInvariant()
{
    Contract.Invariant( matricnumber <= 99999 );
    Contract.Invariant( matricnumber >= 10000 );
    Contract.Invariant( yearmark <= 100 );
    Contract.Invariant( yearmark >= 0 );
}
```

This requires you install Code Contracts from Microsoft [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/), and enable run-time checking.  The `ContractInvariantMethod` provides invariants that must be true when entering and when exiting a method.  If the invariant does not hold, an exception will the thrown.  However, you can configure different failure behavior.

The `Contract` class also has other members that you could use within the property the restriction is applied to.

A more traditional solution would be to use conditional statements to check the requirements on set and handling the error (throw exception, take no action, set to closest bound, etc.) manually.